# How can I duplicate menu items in XCode?

Tags: objective-c, macos, menuitem

I am making a web browsing app in XCode for OS X, and currently I am trying to work on history. I have a menu called history in my `MainMenu.xib`, and I was wondering if it would be possible to add a menu item (through coding) to that every time the user loads a new page.

Answer (score 0):

`NSMenuItem` conforms to the `NSCopying` protocol, so you can copy it with this method:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone;
```

But consider the fact that every field of the menu item gets copied, so also the target and the action.

**PS**: About the zone, pass `NULL` or a pointer to a `NSZone` got with `NSDefaultMallocZone()` .

Comment: I tried [mymenuitem copyWithZone:nil]; but it didn't work. Sorry I'm new to xcode. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Here is something I am trying:                                        NSMenuItem *newmenu = [mymenuitem copyWithZone:nil];  [mymenu addItem:newmenu];

Comment: You should use NULL or you may get a compiler warning. nil is for pointer to objects. Anyway, are you getting some error or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: So all I have to do is [mymenuitem copyWithZone:NULL];?

Comment: Ok. My menu item is called his5. Since I havent done the "Find" item yet either, I put [his5 copyWithZone:NULL]; in the find IBAction. When I run it, I hit the find button, and nothing happens to the history menu. And I have connected the find button to the find IBAction.

Comment: What do you mean by "putting [his5 copyWithZone:NULL]; into the IBAction", can't you show the code?

Comment: -(IBAction)Find:(id)sender
{

    [his5 copyWithZone:NULL];
    
}

Comment: This expression isn't used, you don't catch the return value of copyWithZone: .

Comment: So then what do I do? I am very new at this.

Comment: The discussion is way long to write in comment, join the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/22148/how-can-i-duplicate-menu-items-in-xcode?tab=access It may happen that you don't have the permission to write, in that case join the room and wait for the permission.

Comment: I dont have 20 reputations. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22149/discussion-between-user1936689-and-ramy-al-zuhouri)